# Postgres function and Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, function, npgsql

Does anyone have any idea how to import a Postgres function into an ASP.NET MVC  model using NPGSQL?

I tried but I get "value out of range" error as the result of executing stored procedure, I tried different version of npgsql and Entity Framework but still no success, any comment?